# Відчувати себе чи почуватися?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

В одній [новині](http://www.unn.com.ua/uk/news/1728968-dzhordzha-busha-starshogo-vipisali-z-likarni-pislya-likuvannya-v-zvyazku-iz-zarazhennyam-krovi) є таке речення: "Його лікарі повідомляють, що він відчуває себе добре і щасливий повернутися додому". На перший погляд, помилка, адже стосовно здоров'я треба казати "почувається добре". Та серед значень слова *відчувати*, наведених у СУМ-11, є таке:

> 2. Переживати якесь почуття.    //  **у сполуч. із сл.
>      себе. Почуватися.**

Отже, чи можна вважати сполучення *відчувати себе* (щодо фізичного стану) синонімічним до *почуватися*?

Comment: [Семантична відмінність між поняттями **відчуття**, **почуття** та **чуття**](/q/780) — двоїна?

Comment: @follower, я бачила подібну тему, та тут, на мою думку, питання дещо інше. Там розглядається розрізнення понять, тим паче, в тлумаченні психологічного словника, тобто термінологічне вживання.  А моє запитання стосується не стільки розрізнення за значенням, скільки унормованого вживання варіантів у певному випадку.

Answer (score 1):

Для відповіді на це питання звернемося до сайту [ОнлайнКорректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F/), де бачимо

> Замініть конструкцію **почувати себе**, якщо мовиться про самопочуття, на
>   стилістично кращий варіант: **почуватися**.

Однак, як бачите про "почувати себе" там пише не "не можна", а "не рекомендується", тобто теоретичну такій варіант можна використати, але все ж краще вживати дієслово "почуватися".

Comment: Але ж питання, здається, не про «**по**чувати себе» проти «почуватися», а про «**від**чувати себе» проти «почуватися».

Comment: Просто, згідно до знайденої мною інформації (http://almaschool.com.ua/uk/articles/vdchu-ati-vs-po), ми взагалі не можемо сказати "відчувати себе" (саме "відчувати"), бо: "Дієслово «відчувати» використовується, коли мова йде про сприймання явищ навколишнього світу: зорові, смакові, нюхові, тактильні відчуття. Людина може відчувати смак, біль, тепло або холод". А от "почувати себе" ми якраз можемо вжити: "Дієслово «почувати» використовується, коли мова йде про психологічні стани людини, її емоції. Сюди відносяться почуття обов’язку, почуття гідності, любові або жаху".

Comment: Я думаю, найчастіший спосіб уживання — це: «я почуваюся (фізично як?) добре/погано», але «відчуй себе (умовно ким?) телезіркою». Але СУМ-11 і СУМ-20 це не підтверджують, вони вважають, що «відчувати себе» можна використовувати як при «ким/чим?», так і як синонім до «почуватися». Мабуть, вплинув той факт, що «почуватися» рідко вживається в доконаній формі, а вживати в доконаній формі щось треба, тому «почуватися» й «відчувати себе» зрештою почали змішуватися.

Comment: А щодо джерела http://almaschool.com.ua/uk/articles/vdchu-ati-vs-po — мабуть, варто додати це у відповідь, бо зараз виходить, що відповідь зовсім не торкається теми «відчувати себе» (хоч я з цим джерелом неповністю згоден — але це теж думка).

Comment: Приєднуюсь до Саші. Станом на зараз цей пост - не відповідь на питання. Ставлю мінус до наступної редактури.